# Kubernetes liveness probe httpGet schema not working correctly

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-health-check, kubernetes-deployment, livenessprobe

I am deploying some web app on kubernetes and I want to set liveness probe for this application.
When I configure my deployment with liveness probe, kubelet start health check. I was defined httpGet with scheme "HTTP" parameter but kubelet using https schema randomly.

This is my liveness probe configuration:

```
livenessProbe:
  failureThreshold: 4
  httpGet:
    path: /
    port: 80
    scheme: HTTP
  initialDelaySeconds: 40
  periodSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 2
```

This is result from kubelet:

kubectl describe pod greenlight-7877dc58b7-6s78l

output:

> Warning  Unhealthy  31s (x4 over 46s)  kubelet            Liveness
> probe failed: Get "https://10.244.4.182/": dial tcp 10.244.4.182:443:
> connect: connection refused

Kubernetes version: v1.19.9

Thanx for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are explicitly stating livenessProbe to use HTTP, it's probably your application that redirects traffic to HTTPS. Make sure that your application returns a `200 OK` on basepath `/`, and not a redirection (any of `3xx` codes).

You can either fix that, or use [TCP probe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-a-tcp-liveness-probe)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: goproxy
  labels:
    app: goproxy
spec:
  containers:
  - name: goproxy
    image: k8s.gcr.io/goproxy:0.1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    readinessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 10
    livenessProbe:
      tcpSocket:
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      periodSeconds: 20
```

Comment: Hello Pawel. After the your answer, i checked my deployment.And than i noticed application  redirect request to https. I solved my problem with your feedback. Thank you.